# "Connection must be open for this operation" Exception on ODP

Tags: c#, connection, using, odp.net

I'm calling `OracleCommandd.ExecuteNonquery()` in my applciation and i'm getting "Connection must be open for this operation" exception in the code below:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(procedureName, connection);
            oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

When i place `connection.Open();` just after `using` statement the exception does not occur but isn't `using` statement handling the opening and closing phase of connection(open close actually menas getting and leaving connection fromt/to connection pool).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but isn't using statement handling the opening and closing phase of
>   connection

No. 
The [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) has **nothing** to do with `connection.Open()`

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
{
  connection.Open(); //<-- must have
  //rest of code omitted
}
```

You don't need to call `connection.Close()` because that happens when the connection is disposed. Which is the true purpos of the `using`keyword.

This is what the `using` actually translate into:

```
try
{
  //code omitted
}
finally
{
  connection.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `using` statement is just used for instantiating the object that will be used in the `using` statement's scope. It will close the connection when disposing the connection but it won't open it, you must do it yourself. 
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

```
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
          connection.Open();
          using (OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(procedureName, connection);)
          {
               oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
    }
```

Comment: I like ur approach, but how can you catch exceptions, if at all it raised? Is it a good practice to use both Using statement & try catch block?

Comment: Yeah, you can enclose all this with one try-catch block.